# output format of each tuple in list

Tags: python

I want to print each tuple in the list with certain format like the last line of code most below

This is my array

```
[0.77001903 0.10465796 0.88704993 0.54562736 0.88638223 0.6739792 ]
```

If i make it .tolist() , it would shape like this

```
[0.77001903,  0.10465796 , 0.88704993 , 0.54562736 ,  0.88638223,  0.6739792 ]
```

I thought that since it's already shapes like that then i could feed each of its tuples to the .format to fill all the curly brackets then i just knew that i couldn't do that, it said `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Is there other way to print the tuples with only a list fed to the output?

This code explains what i want to do exactly

```
print('fit time : {} \nscore time : {}\ntest accuracy : {}\ntest precision : {}\ntest recall : {}\ntest f1 score : {}\n'.format(results.tolist()))
```

Comment: if you want as a tuple use `zip(['fit time','score time','test accuracy','test precision','test recall','test f1 score'],results.tolist())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format` takes multiple arguments separately - not as a list. What you need to do is unroll the result list into the argument list to `format`:

```
results = [0.77001903,  0.10465796 , 0.88704993 , 0.54562736 ,  0.88638223,  0.6739792 ]
print('fit time : {} \nscore time : {}\ntest accuracy : {}\ntest precision : {}\ntest recall : {}\ntest f1 score : {}\n'.format(*results))  # note the *
```

Result:

```
fit time : 0.77001903 
score time : 0.10465796
test accuracy : 0.88704993
test precision : 0.54562736
test recall : 0.88638223
test f1 score : 0.6739792
```